# jQuery Validation Enable Submit Button when Valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation on my form and I would like to be able to disable the submit button and change its class, when the form validates. I know I could bind a function on the key up event but I want to know if this is possible from within the jQuery validate framework.  I tried doing what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882406/jquery-disable-button-not-submit-until-field-validates-validation-plugin) suggested, but got nowhere.

I am using [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Just updated my post....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you may be able to get this to work automatically within the options on the Validate plugin itself.

Check out this link on the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) for more information.

```
$("myForm").validate(
   {
       onkeyup: true, 
       onsubmit: false, 
       onclick: true, 
       onfocusout: true
   }
);
```

Comment: As per the documents you referenced, _"a boolean `true` is not a valid value"_ for any of these listed options.  You can only set them to `false` or over-ride them with a custom function.  However, these are already the default behaviors so setting any of them to `true` is not only unnecessary, it could potentially break this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky - This question is 4 years old.  Documents change!  Rather than vote down an answer, you ought to edit it.  make it right.

Comment: [I will not edit an answer if it makes _"the code do something different than what the answer says it does"_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/594235) or like here, I'd have to rewrite the entire answer.  However, I did let you know exactly what this issue is so you'd have every opportunity to fix it yourself.  Once fixed, I'll always reconsider retracting any down-vote I may have cast, and even up-vote if/when appropriate.  In this case, even four years ago, these options were documented and functioned the same as today.